# Did Apple remove the ability to create a Fusion Drive from diskutil in Big Sur?

Tags: disk-utility

When I attempt to do `sudo diskutil cs create` I get the following response:

```
diskutil: did not recognize coreStorage verb "create"; type "diskutil coreStorage" for a list
```

It looks like there's no longer a `create` option available on Big Sur.

```
Usage:  diskutil [quiet] coreStorage|CS <verb> <options>
    where <verb> is as follows:

 list            (Show status of CoreStorage volumes)
 info[rmation]   (Get CoreStorage information by UUID or disk)
 delete          (Delete a CoreStorage logical volume group)
 unlockVolume    (Attach/mount a locked CoreStorage logical volume)

diskutil coreStorage <verb> with no options will provide help on that verb
diskutil: did not recognize coreStorage verb "create"; type "diskutil coreStorage" for a list
```

Is there some other way that is the new intended path to creating a Fusion Drive?

Comment: Try `sudo diskutil apfs createContainer [-main] device [-secondary] [device]`. The main will be considered to be faster than the secondary. Unlike `sudo diskutil cs create lvgName devices ...`, you do not provide a name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Mac Os Mojave the command to create/re-create a Fusion Drive is

```
diskutil resetFusion
```

It's explain here : https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207584

Comment: Thanks very much!  Saved me a bunch of digging.  :-)